# Using the same method several times in one function

Tags: javascript

I wrote a function, which has two `reduce()` methods in it. *There's an array of arrays and the function should first substract elements within each sub-array and then add the received elements.* Although it's working, I guess it's not good from the point of 'DRY' principle. I'd be grateful if someone comment on my code. Thanks.

```js
let result = function(arr){
   return arr.map((item) => item.reduce((a, b) => a - b)).reduce((c, d) => c + d);
};
console.log(result([[8,1],[4,11],[3,9]]))
```

Comment: There is a stackexchange [dedicated to code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), I think you should post your question there instead of here.

Comment: Right now your first function subtracts whereas the second adds. That doesn't seem to match with what you're asking?

Comment: You seem to be subtracting the groups and then adding up the results so they aren't performing the same logic?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question should be posted on/migrated to [Code Review | Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I don't see where you are repeating yourself?

Comment: @Christian G. thank you, I didn't know about that resource

Comment: @Bergi I think I'm repeating myself by using two .reduce() methods in one function

Comment: @an_bozh Nothing wrong with that, especially since their callbacks do different things - if you have different values to loop over, you write multiple loops. In a nested-loops case for when working with nested arrays, there's no other choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this function is supposed to work on an array of tuples only, I wouldn't use `reduce` for the mapping. Just write

```
function result(arr) {
    return arr.map(([a, b]) => a - b).reduce((c, d) => c + d, 0);
}
```

Don't forget to pass the `0` as the initial value to the summing `reduce`, so that your function will still work if you pass an empty array.

You can further shorten the above by fusing the `map` into the `reduce`:

```
function result(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((c, [a, b]) => c + a - b, 0);
}
```

Comment: by the way, I tried to run the functions from your answer, with `0` as the initial value, and they both return `NaN`, when I pass an empty array: `result([[10,0],[3,5],[5,8],[]])` => `NaN`. Did you mean they would ignore that empty array and return a number?

Comment: `function result (arr) {
    return arr.map(([a, b]) => a - b).reduce((c, d) => c + d || 'please fill the empty array', 0);
};  result([[10,0],[3,5],[5,8],[]])` returns **please fill the empty array** ) (when I don't pass the empty array, `result([[10,0],[3,5],[5,8]])` it returns a number). Interesting

Comment: oh, I see, by **'passing and empty array'** you meant `result([])`, not `result([[5,8],[]])`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To complement @Bergi's answer, you could also extract the operations into their own functions to make it a bit more readable:

```js
const arraySub = arr => arr.reduce((a, b) => a - b);
const arraySum = arr => arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
const subAndSum = arr => arraySum(arr.map(arraySub));

console.log(subAndSum([[8,1],[4,11],[3,9]]))
```